# syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code is what im having syntax errors on. I tried following an example website, but I guess I must've put something in the wrong place or didnt add something. If someone could show me what i might've done wrong that would be great.
 The Article model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy,
  validates :title, :text, :category_id, presence: true,
            length: {minimum: 3}
end
```

The category model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot put category_id with minimum 3 since it's referring to record number

here sample validation for your code above

```
validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 3}
validates :text,  presence: true, length: {minimum: 3}
validates :category, presence: true
# category must exist
```

Comment: Thank you, dude)) You've saved my life!)

Answer (score 0):

Delete `,` from line

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

Also I think `length` is not good for `category_id`